# Python,Bokeh: radio button group

Tags: python, bokeh

Cant find a working example of using Radio button group ( [Adding Interaction](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.9.3/docs/user_guide/interaction.html) ). In the documentation there is an example how to create the group, but how can I use it?

For example how can I create a figure with 2 radio button so if i click the one a plot is showed and if i click the other another plot is showed.

Comment: If you solved this one, could you post your own answer? I would like to see how you were able to do it.

Comment: @KobeJohn Im sorry,I wasn't able to solve it. I used the tab panes for my task.

Comment: I believe, [mosc9575](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462392/hide-several-lines-using-checkboxes-and-customjs-in-python-bokeh) solved the proposed example of turning plots on and off in another post using *CheckboxGroup*.

Answer (score 6):

Define the group:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import RadioButtonGroup
radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=['Plot1', 'Plot2'], active=0)
```

Use the following line if you want to act immediately when the radio button is pressed:

```
radio_button_group.on_change('active', lambda attr, old, new: update())
```

The active choice can be accessed in your update() function under:

```
radio_button_group.active
```

Note the values are enumerated: 0 for 'Plot1' and 1 for 'Plot2'