# Hide several lines using Checkboxes and CustomJS in Python Bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

Let say I have 2 different lines:

```
df[0]=fig.line(x = 'x', y = 'y',..., name = 'toto0',source=s0)
df[1]=fig.line(x = 'x', y = 'y',..., name = 'toto1',source=s1)
```

If I want to have to possibility to hide them, I use this piece of code:

```
checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=['toto0','toto1'], active=2, width=100)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(l0=df[0],l1=df[1],checkbox=checkbox),
code="""
l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
""")
checkbox.js_on_change('active', callback)
layout = row(fig,checkbox)
show(layout)
```

Now let's say I have 20 different lines.
How to proceed to compact the code below ?

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(l0=df[0],...,l19=df[19],checkbox=checkbox),
code="""
l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
...
l19.visible = 19 in checkbox.active;
""")
```

This is a Python and a JavaScript question ... thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is to collect all line renderes in a list and pass this list to the CustomJS. There you can loop over this list again and apply your changes.

**Minimal Example**

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import row
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x':range(5), 
     'red':range(5), 
     'blue':list(range(5))[::-1], 
     'green':[2]*5}
)

fig = figure(width=300, height=300)

line_renderer = []
names = list(df.columns[1:])
for name in names:
    line_renderer.append(
        fig.line(
            x = 'x', 
            y = name, 
            color=name,
            name =name, 
            source=df
        )
    )

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=names, active=list(range(len(names))), width=100)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(lines=line_renderer,checkbox=checkbox),
    code="""
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
        lines[i].visible = checkbox.active.includes(i);
    }
    """
)
checkbox.js_on_change('active', callback)
layout = row(fig,checkbox)
show(layout)
```

**Output**

[image: click]

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks ! Array in the JS is what I have missed