# How to translate checked boxes into plots

Tags: python, plot, checkbox, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I hope the title is not too confusing. I have a large Data file with many columns, they all have titles and the data is loaded into pandas, the x-axis should be the date.

Now I want to create an interactive plot with the data, so you can see all the checkboxes and can select, which data should be shown in the plot.

I have found that maybe bokeh is the best way to do it, but I am a bit stuck. I habe already created the checkboxes (checkbox_group), but I dont know how to translate that into a plot.

Obvously I dont want to create around 300 boxes and plots manually, so I am looking for a solution, that takes all the heades and then plots the data from that column if the box is checked.

Comment: I am happy to help, but it is allways the best to show with a code snipped what you have tried so far. If I understand your goal correctly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462392/hide-several-lines-using-customjs-in-python-bokeh/69464359#69464359) could be close to your wanted plot. You only have to have the x-axis type to `datetime`. Let me know if I am right.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what i was looking for. The only thing that I didn't find out yet, is how to make the default, that the boxes are not checked. So that No or maybe only one plot is showing after executing the code. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide several lines using CustomJS in Python Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462392/hide-several-lines-using-customjs-in-python-bokeh)

Comment: I don't have enough "experience" I think :D

Comment: If you have, you may come back.