# How to Hide Span Lines in Bokeh

Tags: html, hide, bokeh, mute, vline

I have a bokeh plot with a scatter and a line plot and many span vlines. The line plot can easily be hidden via the legend, but how do I hide span lines? I want to click on individual span lines to either mute or hide them completely. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I want to show is an adaption from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462392/hide-several-lines-using-customjs-in-python-bokeh/69464359) where checkboxes are used to toggle lines. This can be done for Spans as well.

```python
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import Span, CheckboxGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[1,2,3,4,5], line_width=2, legend_label='Line')
s = []
span_positions = [2.5,3.5]
for pos in span_positions:
    s.append(Span(dimension='height', location=pos))
p.renderers.extend(s)

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(
    labels=['Span_'+str(i) for i in span_positions], 
    active=list(range(len(span_positions))), 
    width=100
)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(spans=s,checkbox=checkbox),
    code="""
    for(var i=0; i<spans.length; i++){
        spans[i].visible = checkbox.active.includes(i);
    }
    """
)
checkbox.js_on_change('active', callback)
layout = row(p,checkbox)
show(layout)
```

**Output**

[image: toggle spans]

**Comment**

I tried to add Spans to the legend to avoid CheckBoxes, but I was not able to, because `LegendItem` from bokeh does not accept Spans. So this might not be ideal.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!