# bokehjs: computing a new plot automatically as sum of all activated plots

Tags: python, bokeh

Having 3 line plots in Bokehjs, I would like Bokeh to show a fourth one, which is the sum of the other 3.
Example:

```
y1=[1,2,3,4,5]
y2=[4,5,6,7,8]
y3=[1,8,2,6,4]
```

Automatically generated plot would be:

```
y_all = [6,15,11,17,17]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?
Maybe with a js callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want, so I start with a very basic approche.

I assume you can use `pandas`. And your given DataFrame is this:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'y1':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'y2':[4,5,6,7,8],
    'y3':[1,8,2,6,4],
})
```

**Static solution**

With [`pandas.DataFrame.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html?highlight=sum#pandas.DataFrame.sum) you can create the sum and then you can use [`multi_line`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html?highlight=multi_line#bokeh.plotting.Figure.multi_line) from bokeh.

```
df['y_all'] = df.sum(axis=1)
p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.multi_line(
    xs=[df.index]*4, ys=list(df.values.T), color=['red', 'green','blue', 'black']
)
show(p)
```

[image: multi_line plot]

**Interactive solution**

Because you mentioned JS, I created an interactive solution. This solution is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462392/hide-several-lines-using-customjs-in-python-bokeh/69464359#69464359).

Here the sum is calculated on the fly by the selection given by the active CheckBoxes.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'y1':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'y2':[4,5,6,7,8],
    'y3':[1,8,2,6,4],
})

df['y_all'] = df.sum(axis=1)
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

colors = ['red', 'green','blue', 'black']

p = figure(width=300, height=300)

line_renderer = []
names = list(df.columns)
for name, color in zip(names, colors):
    line_renderer.append(
        p.line(
            x = 'index',
            y = name,
            color=color,
            name =name,
            source=source
        )
    )
checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=names, active=list(range(len(names))), width=100)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(lines=line_renderer,checkbox=checkbox, source=source),
    code="""
    const data = source.data;
    for (let i = 0; i < data['y_all'].length; i++) {
        data['y_all'][i] = 0
    }

    for(var j=0; j<lines.length; j++){
        lines[j].visible = checkbox.active.includes(j);
    }

    console.log(data)
    console.log(checkbox)
    for(var item of checkbox.active){
        let next_y = lines[item]["properties"]["name"]["spec"]["value"]
        if (next_y != 'y_all'){
            for (let i = 0; i < data[next_y].length; i++) {
                data['y_all'][i] += data[next_y][i]
            }
        }
    }
    source.change.emit();
    """
)
checkbox.js_on_change('active', callback)
layout = row(p,checkbox)
show(layout)
```

[image: interacitve sum]

Comment: the interactive solution is pretty awesome! Thank you!